# Bash : grep -i -vFf

Tags: bash

I have 20 files. In each file I have a list of the occurring words and their frequency. 
example

```
5 hi
10 test
20 bye 
5 Hello
```

etc

And another file in which there is a list of words.

```
hi   
Hello 
goodbye
```

How can I use one grep -v on all of these ?
I tried

```
for i in  {1..20} ; 
do
grep -i -vFf ./../data/input/blacklist.txt ./../data/dico/$i.dico.forme.lemme.txt > ./../data/selection/$i.select.txt  ;
done
```

But it didn't work.   
What I expect was to have

```
10 test
20 bye
```

what I get

```
5 hi
10 test
20 bye
5 Hello
```

Comment: Does this work on a single file? If not, why not?

Comment: When you say "use one `grep -v`", what do you mean? What exactly do you want to achieve? And what does "didn't work" mean exactly? What output did you expect, what did you get? You also don't have representative sample input.

Comment: You already claimed last week that the same code does not work as expected. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48127752/grep-doesnt-work-like-expected. If you don't provide a [MCVE] it is guesswork (at best).

Comment: If you have `hi\nHello` in blacklist.txt and the 4 lines in lemme.txt you get 2 lines as result out of `grep -i -vFf blacklist.txt lemme.txt`. If you want to work on all files just `grep -i -vFf blacklist.txt *lemme.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I created the files according to your specification and dit the grep:

```
ljm[tmp]$ cat lemme
5 hi
10 test
20 bye 
5 Hello
ljm[tmp]$ cat blacklist
hi
Hello
ljm[tmp]$ grep -ivf blacklist lemme 
10 test
20 bye
```

This means that it should work. Apparently, you are doing something different  than you stated in your question.

Comment: I think the problem is that there is some words in the blacklist that are not written in the main file

Comment: That would surprise me, as adding some other words to the blacklist does not produce that effect. What I was thinking, is that you might have Windows/DOS line-endings in your blacklist (`\r\n` ) instead of the standard Unix line endings (`\n`).